# Show one row if all values except one column are equal

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I usually show shipping status of the order, product by product. But I want the show only one row (doesn't matter which one) when all values except 'item' are the same. I tried `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but for both I need to exclude 'item' column.

```
| item | status  | ship_date  | est_ship_date | order_num | tracking_number |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| abc  | Shipped | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-01    | 123       | xyz             |
| cde  | Shipped | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-01    | 123       | xyz             |
| efg  | Shipped | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-01    | 123       | xyz             |
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item, status, ship_date, est_ship_date, order_num, tracking_number 
from orders
where order_num = 123
```

I know if I exclude item I will get one row but I have to keep it. I can't exclude 'item'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by status, ship_date, est_ship_date, order_num, tracking_number
            order by item
        ) rn
    from mytable t 
) t
where rn = 1
```

When duplicate exists on `(status, ship_date, est_ship_date, order_num, tracking_number)`, this gives you the row with the smallest `item`.

Another option is aggregation (it works because you are excluding only one column):

```
select status, ship_date, est_ship_date, order_num, tracking_number, min(item) item
from mytable
group by status, ship_date, est_ship_date, order_num, tracking_number
```

Comment: which one is the table name in row_number

Comment: @EvikGhazarian: that's `mytable`

Comment: aggregation worked Thank you. The first option was still giving back multiple rows